# Hotkeys and Windows Key in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu

Many different shortcuts are enabled in windows and they can be useful. What I wanted to do was disable the windows key from opening the start menu in Windows 10. This can be done with Sharpkeys and I have done this and disabled the key but this disables useful shortcuts such as Win + R. My overall plan was to use Wox instead which would be enabled when I press the windows key but I have not found a way of doing this while searching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to set Winkey to still be useable as modifier, but not for
launching the Start Menu.

The only solution I can think of requires using an alternative product for the
Start Menu.

One of the best alternatives is the free and open-source
[Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu).

After installing it, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*Right-click* to go into Settings,
then into the *Controls* tab, expand "Windows Key Opens",
change it to "Nothing" and click OK.